# built vs had built

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

What is the difference between the two sentences below

> A: He learned about good design from the house where his family lived.
>      An architect called John **had built** it.
>
> B: He learned about good design from the house where his family lived.
>      An architect called John **built** it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=past+perfect+vs+past

You would likely enjoy the site http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think 'had built' is appropriate here. 'Built' denotes a very recent past whereas 'had built' shows history.

Comment: If simple past denotes a very recent past, is "He had learned ..." better than "He learned ..." if writer of the sentence A is telling a story happened many years ago? But, is it normal to use past perfect tense twice in a row ?

Comment: Simple past does note denote very recent past. Likewise, past perfect does not denote very distant past. And any tense can be used any number of times in a row.